# Why does flyout mobile menu appear below <div id="custom-header-code" class="topheader"> on mobile phone?

Tags: css, wordpress

When I test [the page](https://mdpen.co/) in a browser using the webmaster tools to emulate an iPhone, everything looks okay. The mobile menu overlays everything and is completely visible. But when I actually [visit the website](https://mdpen.co/) on my iPhone, the top part of the flyout menu is obscured by a div which is added to the HTML by a WordPress function. It is hidden by CSS on desktop.

How can I fix it so the menu is on top???

Here is a simplified version of my generated HTML. The asterisks indicate the relevant parts.

```
<body>
**<div id="custom-header-code" class="topheader">content</div>**
<div id="gen-wrap" class="wrapper">
    <header> <!-- for mobile -->
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div id="header-logo">content</div>
            <div id="mobile-container-toggle">content</div>
            **<div id="mobile-container">flyout menu content</div>**
            <div id="mobile-container-overlay"></div>
    </header> <!-- for mobile -->
    <header> <!-- for desktop -->
        <!-- content -->
    </header> <!-- for desktop -->
</div>
```

I have tried setting the z-index for different elements.

Answer (score -1):

The div WP adds is outside the main wrap, so it will sit above everything. Try adding.

```
#gen-wrap {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: I set the `z-index: 9999999;` but still not working. Also made sure `<div id="custom-header-code">` doesn't have a specified position or z-index at all.

Comment: Which div is WP adding in? I thought you may of meant the admin bar?

Comment: `<div id="custom-header-code" class="topheader">content</div>`

Comment: I checked on both Android and an iPhone device and I'm not seeing the issue. The .topheader doesn't have any z-index or positioning therefor no reason for it to sit above the flyout menu.

You could try adding something like.

.topheader {
 z-index: -1;
 position: relative;
}

and see if it helps on your end.

Comment: We currently have a JavaScript that adds a css style to hide the topheader when the menu toggle is active. But that is just a bandaid and I would prefer to fix the problem.